# Warning: argument 1 does not name a graphical parameter in R

Tags: r, diagnostics, stan, rstan

I'm currently working on **rstan**. After fitting the moedel, I try to perform a bit diagnostic plotting, and I use the following syntax `pairs(x = fit, pars = c("alpha", "beta"))`. The `fit` is my `stanfit` object, meanwhile **alpha** and **beta** are the parameters of the `fit`. I kept getting `Warning: argument 1 does not name a graphical parameter`.

Does anybody know what does this warning imply, and what should I do to solve the problem? Thanks in advance!

---

I searched online for this warning message, and surprisingly, there are not many questions on this, so I suppose this could be a studpid problem which I didn't notice.

I used syntax `pairs(~ alpha + beta, data = fit)`, which worked but didn't output the ideal plots I need.

Comment: Do you intend something like `pairs( ..., par(col = 'red'))`?

Comment: Tried that, it did turn my frame color into red, but not what I intended actually. My plots are okay, but tbh I just want to solve the warning message.

Comment: If the formula notation `pairs(~ ...)` works, and the plots are OK, why not just skip the `pars = ...` thing and, thus, the warning?

Comment: Oh it's because `pairs(~...)` produces a matrix scatter plot without gradient (by gradient I mean darker color where dots are denser and lighter where dots are scarce), I need to check whether there are multiple peaks in my parameter space.